# append not working in Safari

Tags: jquery

I have an html div that is show in the page depending on the url if it does match, the div is showing in all of browsers except in Safari.

I did call it by append method. Thank you in advance.

```
var yeah = $('
  <div class="proactive-chat-container right-bottom" id="proactive-chat">
  <div class="panel panel-info" id="proactive-chat-popover">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="panel-media trycss" style="transition-delay: 0.1s; display: block;">
        <a href="#"><img src="/media/13583787/1.jpg" style="margin-top: -7px"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-header">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Trend Micro Support</h4>
        <p class="panel-subtitle" id="proactive-chat-status">Usually replies in few minutes</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-heading-button">
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-close"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="proactive-chat-message">
      <div class="proactive-chat-message-content">
        <p>' + msg + '</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <a class="btn chat-with-us" id="testSecond">
          <span>Chat with us</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="two" style="display: none">
      <div class="proactive-chat-message-content">
        <p>Please enter your information</p>
        <form id="frmENCONS" name="frmENCONS" onsubmit="return false">
          <div id="hiddenFieldContainer">
            <input id="txtPhoneNumber" name="txtPhoneNumber" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="txtSerialNumber" name="txtSerialNumber" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="ddlProductName" name="ddlProductName" type="hidden" value="GENERIC PRODUCT">
            <input id="hidAccessID" name="hidAccessID" type="hidden" value="ENCONS">
            <input id="ddlCountry" name="ddlCountry" type="hidden" value="' + _countryName + '">
            <input id="ddlOperatingSystem" name="ddlOperatingSystem" type="hidden" value="N/A">
            <input id="txtProblemDescription" name="txtProblemDescription" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="hidLanguage" name="hidLanguage" type="hidden" value="English">
            <input id="hidGIC" name="hidGIC" type="hidden" value="ZZZZZZZZZ">
            <input id="hidVersionName" name="hidVersionName" type="hidden" value="Not Available">
            <input id="hidInternetConnName" name="hidInternetConnName" type="hidden" value="Not Available">
            <input type="hidden" id="hidRefUrl" name="hidRefUrl" value="' + window.location.href + '">
            <input id="hidUrlFrom" name="hidUrlFrom" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="hidCountryCode" name="hidCountryCode" type="hidden" value="' + _countryCode + '">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label class="control-label" for="txtFirstName">First Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="txtFirstName" name="txtFirstName" onchange="checkFname(this.value)" placeholder="First Name" required type="text">
          <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label class="control-label" for="txtLastName">Last Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="txtLastName" name="txtLastName" onchange="checkLname(this.value)" placeholder="Last Name" required type="text">
          <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group has-feedback">
          <label class="control-label" for="txtEmailAddress">Email Address</label>
          <input class="form-control" id="txtEmailAddress" name="txtEmailAddress" onkeyup="checkEmail(this.value);" placeholder="Email Address" required type="email">
          <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
      <a class="btn" onclick="submitForm(event)">
        <span>Start Chat</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info hide" id="proactive-chat-alert">
  <div class="panel-body text-center">
    <h4>Trend Micro Support</h4>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="proactive-loading">
      <img src="/media/13583778/proactive-icon-loading.gif">
    </p>
    <br>
    <div class="proactive-chat-alert-icon">
    <p>
      <img src="/media/13583760/proactive-icon-primary.png">
    </p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <p class="proactive-loading-state">Our Support Representative will be with you shortly.
  </p>
</div>
```

```
');

$(yeah).appendTo('body').delay(1000).fadeIn(2200);
```

Comment: Firstly, recommend breaking up that var - what is it? it looks like a html string but is being called like a selector , and recommended way is doing: `$('body').append(htmlStr)`

Comment: Have you considered a templating solution like Handlebars or ReactJS? That inline html is a bit nuts.

Comment: _“depending on the url if it does match”_ – and you have of course verified that it is not actually this check that goes wrong in Safari …?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs - That's how you create a document fragment in jQuery, it's perfectly valid if a bit misguided to do it that way (instead of a template).

Comment: @JaredFarrish ah I see - seems like a really odd weird thing to do haha

Comment: i have a condition that checks the url then I'll append the div. It works on Chrome and other browsers except safari.

Comment: $('body').append(yeah) i have tried this already but still does not work in safari

Comment: Please provide a link if possible and explain how to trigger it occurring.

Comment: `$('body').append(yeah)` works just fine in Safari when I try it.  What doesn't work is your multi-line definition of `yeah`; that throws an unterminated string literal in every browser.  Can we assume that's a single line in your real code?  (Collapsing it to a single line and setting values for `msg`, `_countryCode` and `_countryName` worked fine in Safari for me.)

Comment: yes its on my ajax request using jquery async false. when i removed it runs. i did not include the ajax because i thought the append method is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Anyways thank you all for answering